# Estructura de un csv

Tags: csv, openldap

Estoy intentando cargar dos usuarios usando un fichero .csv y me da el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este momento ya no se donde me falta las "" o donde me sobra

El contenido del fichero es el siguiente

```
dn_suffix,dn_rdn,inetOrgPerson_firstName,inetOrgPerson_lastName,inetOrgPerson_initials,inetOrgPerson_email,posixAccount_userName,posixAccount_cn,posixAccount_group,posixAccount_additionalGroups,posixAccount_homedir,posixAccount_shell,posixAccount_password,posixAccount_gecos,shadowAccount_expireDate
"ou=profes,ou=usuarios,dc=proxecto-julio,dc=local,uid,Jose Miguel,Bardal,J.M.,jmiguel@proxecto-julio.local,jmiguel,PROFES – Jose Miguel Bardal,""g-daw2-profes,"",/home/jmiguel,/bin/bash,abc123.,PROFES Jose Miguel Bardal,31-12-1969"
"ou=daw2,ou=alum,ou=usuarios,dc=proxecto-julio,dc=local,uid,Julio,Pillado,J.P.,jpillado@proxecto-julio.local,jpillado,DAW2 – Julio Pillado,""g-daw2-alumnos,"",/home/jpillado,/bin/bash,abc123.,DAW2 Julio Pillado,31-12-1970"
```

**--- OTRAS FORMAS QUE PROBRE --**

```
dn_suffix,dn_rdn,inetOrgPerson_firstName,inetOrgPerson_lastName,inetOrgPerson_initials,inetOrgPerson_email,posixAccount_userName,posixAccount_cn,posixAccount_group,posixAccount_additionalGroups,posixAccount_homedir,posixAccount_shell,posixAccount_password,posixAccount_gecos,shadowAccount_expireDate
"ou=profes,ou=usuarios,dc=proxecto-julio,dc=local","uid","Jose Miguel,"Bardal","J.M.","jmiguel@proxecto-julio.local","jmiguel","PROFES – Jose Miguel Bardal","g-daw2-profes","","/home/jmiguel","/bin/bash","abc123.","PROFES Jose Miguel Bardal","31-12-1969"
"ou=daw2,ou=alum,ou=usuarios,dc=proxecto-julio,dc=local","uid","Julio","Pillado","J.P.","jpillado@proxecto-julio.local","jpillado","DAW2 – Julio Pillado","g-daw2-alumnos","","/home/jpillado","/bin/bash","abc123.","DAW2 Julio Pillado","31-12-1970"
```

```
dn_suffix,dn_rdn,inetOrgPerson_firstName,inetOrgPerson_lastName,inetOrgPerson_initials,inetOrgPerson_email,posixAccount_userName,posixAccount_cn,posixAccount_group,posixAccount_additionalGroups,posixAccount_homedir,posixAccount_shell,posixAccount_password,posixAccount_gecos,shadowAccount_expireDate
ou=profes,ou=usuarios,dc=proxecto-julio,dc=local,uid,Jose Miguel,Bardal,J.M.,jmiguel@proxecto-julio.local,jmiguel,PROFES – Jose Miguel Bardal,g-daw2-profes,,/home/jmiguel,/bin/bash,abc123.,PROFES Jose Miguel Bardal,31-12-1969
ou=daw2,ou=alum,ou=usuarios,dc=proxecto-julio,dc=local,uid,Julio,Pillado,J.P.,jpillado@proxecto-julio.local,jpillado,"DAW2 – Julio Pillado,g-daw2-alumnos,,/home/jpillado,/bin/bash,abc123.,DAW2 Julio Pillado,31-12-1970
```

```
dn_suffix,dn_rdn,inetOrgPerson_firstName,inetOrgPerson_lastName,inetOrgPerson_initials,inetOrgPerson_email,posixAccount_userName,posixAccount_cn,posixAccount_group,posixAccount_additionalGroups,posixAccount_homedir,posixAccount_shell,posixAccount_password,posixAccount_gecos,shadowAccount_expireDate
"ou=profes,ou=usuarios,dc=proxecto-julio,dc=local","uid","Jose Miguel,"Bardal","J.M.","jmiguel@proxecto-julio.local","jmiguel","PROFES – Jose Miguel Bardal","g-daw2-profes",,"/home/jmiguel","/bin/bash","abc123.","PROFES Jose Miguel Bardal","31-12-1969"
"ou=daw2,ou=alum,ou=usuarios,dc=proxecto-julio,dc=local","uid","Julio","Pillado","J.P.","jpillado@proxecto-julio.local","jpillado","DAW2 – Julio Pillado","g-daw2-alumnos",,"/home/jpillado","/bin/bash","abc123.","DAW2 Julio Pillado","31-12-1970"
```

He probado ha hacerlo de varias maneras pero sigo sin dar con la correcta

Comment: Creo que ldapadd piensa que toda la linea es el primero campo.  Es decir "ou=profes,ou=usuarios,dc=proxecto.... etc" es dn_suffix y no hay nada para los otros campos.  Que pasa si borra las comillas o usarlas por text?  ou=profes,out=usario... etc o "ou=profes","ou=usarios",'dc=proxecto",...etc ?

Comment: @Duston probé a ponerlos con los campos separados por comillas y sin comillas pero sigue dando error